# How to optimize a function for calculating distribution similarity

Tags: python, function, numpy, optimization, numpy-ndarray

I have a dataframe with different actors distribution of attention towards different issues. It looks like this:

```
              Social politics & Welfare  Technology & IT  Business, Finance, & Economy   ...
actor_1                        0.034483         0.051724                       0.017241   ...
actor_2                        0.032000         0.016000                       0.056000   ...
actor_3                        0.012195         0.004065                       0.010163   ...
actor_4                        0.000000         0.045977                       0.022989   ...
actor_5                        0.027397         0.006849                       0.000000   ...
actor_6                        0.128205         0.000000                       0.051282   ...
```

I've created two functions for creating a matrix with the similarity scores between all the different actors.

```
def dist_sim(array1, array2):
    array1 = array1*100
    array2 = array2*100
    distances = array1-array2
    total_distance = 0
    for distance in distances:
        total_distance += math.sqrt(distance*distance)
    return(100-total_distance/2)

def dist_sim_matrix(df):
    matrix = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        party_matrix = []
        for index1, row1 in df.iterrows():
            party_matrix.append(dist_sim(row, row1))
        matrix.append(party_matrix)
    return np.array(matrix, int)
```

They work perfectly fine, however when I apply it to a large dataframe (eg. with 2000 different actors and 25 issues) it takes forever (I'm actually not sure I've got enough RAM for it?).

I'm new in the business of creating my own functions, so any help on optimization would be awesome!

Comment: Did you mean to take `math.sqrt()` outside (i.e. after) the loop?

Comment: You'll want to move all of the looping that you can out of Python by using vectorized `numpy` functions (looping over the data still happens, just in optimized, lower-level code that's much faster). E.g. for `dist_sim`, you can say `total_distance = np.sqrt(distance ** 2).sum()` to remove the loop. Then, instead of doing a nested loop for the whole matrix, you could generalize `dist_sim` so that it can, e.g., compute the distance between one vector and the entire matrix at once (this gets rid of one loop) or between the whole matrix at once (eliminating both loops).

Comment: I don't have time to write a good example of how to do that, but look at broadcasting for `numpy` arrays. You could also consider using `numba.jit` (http://numba.pydata.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Here what you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# I used a fake dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'c1': np.random.rand(10),
                        'c2': np.random.rand(10),
                        'c3': np.random.rand(10),
                        'c4': np.random.rand(10)},
                  index=[f'actor_{i}' for i in range(1,11)])

# Traspose it
df = df.T

# Define the function to compute distance 
def dist_sim(array1, array2):
    ''' 
    Use vectorization, distributive property and numpy functions
    '''

    d = np.sqrt((np.square(array1-array2)).sum())*100
    return(100-d/2)

# Initialize an empty dataframe
sim_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(df), index=list(df))

# cycle over the dataframe actors - exploit symmetry to half iteration number
for i,c1 in enumerate(list(df)):
    for c2 in list(df)[i:]:

        sim_df.loc[c1, c2]=sim_df.loc[c2, c1]=dist_sim_opt(df[c1], df[c2])
```

The resulting dataframe is something like

```
sim_df

          actor_1  actor_2  actor_3  ...  actor_8  actor_9 actor_10
actor_1       100   67.146  56.3693  ...  74.2303  77.7915  55.0946
actor_2    67.146      100  64.7546  ...  61.9146  72.5428  63.7388
actor_3   56.3693  64.7546      100  ...  57.5318  51.5127  95.3162
actor_4   68.5392  59.2313  75.0851  ...  73.3381  61.7608  74.6694
actor_5    72.671  67.2219  79.2112  ...  64.2796  59.9031  77.3241
actor_6   62.8109  67.1849  87.7293  ...  60.9305  53.3952  83.9605
actor_7   62.0589  63.5562  35.7006  ...  57.5888  61.3989  33.1785
actor_8   74.2303  61.9146  57.5318  ...      100   69.602  55.4216
actor_9   77.7915  72.5428  51.5127  ...   69.602      100  51.4612
actor_10  55.0946  63.7388  95.3162  ...  55.4216  51.4612      100
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case there is an optimised function in `scipy`, see the [`spatial.distance`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html) module, specifically the [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist) function for computing:

> Pairwise distances between observations in n-dimensional space.

in your case you can do:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

d = distance.squareform(distance.pdist(df, 'euclidean'))
dd = pd.DataFrame(d, df.index, df.index)
```

note that these are "distances", so the distance to the same actor is zero.  if you really want to have it take a maximal value (as in your calculations) you could do:

```
d *= -50
d += 100
```

before turning into a dataframe.  note that I'm doing these calculations "inplace" so that additional copies of a potentially enormous matrix aren't created